# Sending params to a function when $(document).on

Tags: jquery, onclick, document, jquery-events

I have been working around with an element that was not yet visible in the DOM, hence jQuery wouldn't be able to use the function "click" to it.

Finally, found the way around to make it work, using `$(document).on` and listening for the event globally in the document.

```
$(document).on('click', '.view_usermame', user_view);
```

Here's my simple question; I have the function user_view which is expecting one parameter, the username, so I would need to send the username of the clicked used... **so how do you approach this?**

I'm looking for something like...

```
$(document).on('click', '.view_usermame', user_view(.view_usermame.HTML));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Not sure what you mean by .view_usermame.HTML but see below code. here is how you can pass parameter.

```
$(document).on('click', '.view_usermame', function() {
    user_view(param);
});
```

Comment: Yeap, problem is, I need the text of the clicked CSS as param.

Comment: CodeThing Mate!!! Thanks alot! working like charm and doesn't mix up with the content of the different Ids! really appreciated!